# Binary search using iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

The question is in the comment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> ivec = {15,17,19,25,45,78,98};
    auto beg = ivec.begin() , end = ivec.end();
    auto mid = beg + (end-beg)/2;
    int sought;
    cin>>sought;
    while(mid != end && *mid !=sought) //why not "mid != beg"?
    {
        if(*mid>sought)
            end = mid;
        if(*mid<sought)
            beg = mid + 1;
        mid = beg + (end-beg)/2;
    }
    if(*mid == sought)
        cout<<"Found";
    else
        cout<<"Not Found";
}
```

According to C++ Primer 5th Edition,at the end of the while, mid will be equal to end or it will denote the element for which we are looking. If mid equals end, then the element was not in text.

I ran the program after replacing `end` with `beg` and it runs just fine.

Comment: is it way off topic if I post a nicer implementation as an answer? This code has a number of features that makes me wince (I realize the code is from a book).

Comment: Is this code from the book? It seems incorrect for me - it can lead to UB.

Comment: @NirFridman It would be very helpful if you do.

Comment: @Slava yes it is from c++ primer.

Comment: @Toy_Soldier if this is exact code then quality of this book is questionable (unless it is intentional and book explains what is wrong in this code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why not "mid != beg"?

Because it would break this program after it is fixed, currently it is already broken. So first you have to make it correct, as your code contradicts what you say:

> at the end of the while, mid will be equal to end or it will denote the element for which we are looking

So last condition must be:

```
if(mid != end)
    cout<<"Found";
else
    cout<<"Not Found";
```

Otherwise you would get UB when you enter `sought` > 98 in your example.

Now after fixing your program if you replace `mid != end` to `mid != beg` in the while loop condition, your algorithm will break - for example it will always say "Found" for one element vector.

Answer (score 4):

`end`, the past the end iterator, denotes an invalid element, thus it cannot be dereferenced. You have to first make sure `mid` is not `end`, so you can compare the pointed value.

Your version might invoke undefined behavior and would not work if the sought elem is the first.

Comment: Even this version can have UB - `mid` is not checked to be valid before dereference